# What is @PostMapping annotation in Spring Web MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

For what purpose `@PostMapping` annotation is used in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spring Framework 4.3** has introduced `@PostMapping` annotation.

`@PostMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a **shortcut** for

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Similarly the following annotations are available:

```
@GetMapping  
@PutMapping
@DeleteMapping
@PatchMapping
```

These annotations can improve the readability of code.

**Reference:** [Spring API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html).

Answer (score 10):

`@PostMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

@PostMapping annotated methods handle the HTTP POST requests matched with given `URI expression.` e.g.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/members", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public void addMember(@RequestBody Member member) {
    //code
}
```

Follows this :[example](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-framework-4-3-new-feature-requestmapping-getmapping-postmapping-putmapping-deletemapping)

Hope this helps..!